# "Property does not exist on this collection instance" error while joining in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

**UserAcademyController.php**

```
    public function view_video()
{
    $materialList = DB::table('material')
        ->join('material_group', 'material.group_id', '=', 'material_group.id')
        ->select('material.*', 'material_group.group_thumbnail_url')
        ->get();

    return view('user-academy.view_video', ['materialList' => $materialList]);
}
```

**view_video.blade.php**

```
 @foreach ($materialList as $material)
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="{!! url('user-academy/view/' . $material->id)!!}">
                    @if($material->thumbnail_url !== null)
                        <img src="{{$material->thumbnail_url}}"
                             style="width: 700px; height: 300px">
                    @elseif($materialList->group_thumbnail_url !== null)
                        <img src="{{$materialList->group_thumbnail_url}}"
                             style="width: 700px; height: 300px">
                    @elseif($material->thumbnail_url !== null && $materialList->group_thumbnail_url !== null)
                        <img src="http://www.independentmediators.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/placeholder-image.jpg"
                             style="width: 700px; height: 300px">
                    @endif
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 class="pull-right text-success">${{$material->price}} </h4>

                    <h4>
                        <a href="{!! url('user-academy/view/' . $material->id)   !!}">{{ $material->title }}</a>
                    </h4>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="description">{!!  $material->description  !!}  </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

[This is the "material" table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYA3z.png)

[This is the "material_group" table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr2xv.png)

I get this error even though I copied everything exactly from laravel documentations and followed many videos on this topic I am a new programmer so this may be a very obvious mistake but I have spent a fair share of time looking at the code and just cannot find where the error is!

Comment: $materialList is a collection, so $materialList->group_thumbnail_url is trying to get a property from a collection. Any -> calls on the collection will result in this error.

Comment: *"Any -> calls on the collection will result in this error."* Not exactly; Collection methods like `->chunk()`, `->contains()`, etc. (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods) are perfectly fine. Property accessors (like `->group_thumbnail_url`, without the `()`) will be errors.

Comment: Good catch @TimLewis

Comment: I think this `$materialList->group_thumbnail_url` should be `$material->group_thumbnail_url`

Comment: Thanks guys but now I am getting another error  "Undefined property: stdClass::$group_thumbnail_url" the code is the same with (materialList to material) and it was working for a while but now I don't know what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `group_thumbnail_url` property on `Collection` class which is for sure not exist, that's why you got that error.

the solution is to replace `$materialList->group_thumbnail_url` by `material->group_thumbnail_url`

Comment: Wow do i feel stupid! Thank you so much I was stuck here for days!

Comment: Now I am getting the "Undefined property: stdClass::$group_thumbnail_url" error I don't know what I just did but the code is same

Comment: if you still have the error try to print the content of `$material` object by using `dd` function. `dd($material)` @AsheshNepal